# nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/async/AsyncRequestTimeoutException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have a spring(4) mvc app where I configured a spring web flow. Hitting the flow url (/context/pizza/buy), I am getting this exception. Full exception trace

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/SpringWeb] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/async/AsyncRequestTimeoutException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestTimeoutException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:163)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1193)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1030)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

DispatcherServlet Configuration:

```
package spittr.config.flow;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import    org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.webflow.config.AbstractFlowConfiguration;
import org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices;
import org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutor;
import org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator;


import spittr.config.WebConfig;

@Configuration
public class WebFlowConfig extends AbstractFlowConfiguration{

@Autowired
private WebConfig webConfig;

@Bean
public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
    return getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
    return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder(flowBuilderServices())
            .setBasePath("/WEB-INF/flows")
            .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml").build();
}

@Bean
public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
    return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
            .setViewFactoryCreator(mvcViewFactoryCreator())
            .setDevelopmentMode(true)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public MvcViewFactoryCreator mvcViewFactoryCreator() {
    MvcViewFactoryCreator factoryCreator = new MvcViewFactoryCreator();
    factoryCreator.setViewResolvers(Arrays.<ViewResolver>asList(this.webConfig.viewResolver()));
    factoryCreator.setUseSpringBeanBinding(true);
    return factoryCreator;
}
}


public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

    return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class, WebConfig.class, WebFlowConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

    return new Class<?>[] { };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {

    return new String[] {"/"};
}

@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {

    registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp/spittr/uploads"));
}
}
```

Spring Mvc Configuration:

```
package spittr.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver;
import org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping;


import spittr.config.flow.PizzaFlowHandler;
import spittr.config.flow.WebFlowConfig;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"spittr.web"})
public class WebConfig 
    extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private WebFlowConfig webFlowConfig;

@Bean
public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
    FlowHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
    handlerMapping.setFlowRegistry(this.webFlowConfig.flowRegistry());
    return handlerMapping;
}

@Bean
public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
    FlowHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
    handlerAdapter.setFlowExecutor(this.webFlowConfig.flowExecutor());
    handlerAdapter.setSaveOutputToFlashScopeOnRedirect(true);
    return handlerAdapter;
}

@Bean(name="pizza/buy")
public PizzaFlowHandler pizzaFlowHandler() {
    return new PizzaFlowHandler();
}



@Bean
public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
    TilesConfigurer tiles = new TilesConfigurer();
    tiles.setDefinitions(new String[] {
            "/WEB-INF/layout/tiles.xml"
    });
    tiles.setCheckRefresh(true);

    return tiles;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    return new TilesViewResolver();
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}


@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() throws IOException {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}

}
```

Spring Web Flow Configuration:

```
package spittr.config.flow;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.webflow.config.AbstractFlowConfiguration;
import org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices;
import org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutor;
import org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator;


import spittr.config.WebConfig;

@Configuration
public class WebFlowConfig extends AbstractFlowConfiguration{

@Autowired
private WebConfig webConfig;

@Bean
public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
    return getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
    return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder(flowBuilderServices())
            .setBasePath("/WEB-INF/flows")
            .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml").build();
}

@Bean
public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
    return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
            .setViewFactoryCreator(mvcViewFactoryCreator())
            .setDevelopmentMode(true)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public MvcViewFactoryCreator mvcViewFactoryCreator() {
    MvcViewFactoryCreator factoryCreator = new MvcViewFactoryCreator();
    factoryCreator.setViewResolvers(Arrays.<ViewResolver>asList(this.webConfig.viewResolver()));
    factoryCreator.setUseSpringBeanBinding(true);
    return factoryCreator;
}

}
```

Defined flow directory hierarchies:

[image]

Edited: pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mujahid.home</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringWeb</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringWeb Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.3.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.webflow/spring-webflow -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>m1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-jsp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>SpringWeb</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java-version}</source>
                        <target>${java-version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                        <server>TomcatServer</server>
                        <path>/SpringWeb</path>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you used maven for your application? If yes, could you please add pom.xml.. if not , would like to see which jars you have used in your application

Comment: yes, please see Edited:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem seems to be with the spring-web.jar - how it is getting resolved. It is getting resolved as transitive dependency of spring-webflow-2.4.4-Release.jar. (Please see the left hand side of the attached file.)

[image]

And resolved dependency is spring-web:4.3.0.Release (Right hand side of the image). And this jar doesn't contain the class for which you are getting an exception. You can download the jar from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/4.3.0.RELEASE) and check it out.

To solve this problem, add direct dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This will override the transitive dependency added by spring-webflow. Though I haven't tried this locally, this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Mujahidul Islam!